# CI-HMVC-Doctrine routing error in Unix Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, routes, codeigniter-hmvc

I just finished testing the website on Windows server. The whole website was being made and tested in Windows environment. Everything is working fine but as I launch the website to a server with UNIX environment, I am getting the following error.

> http://wevte.com/test/
>   Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

Comment: Possible case-sensetivity issue perhaps? Windows isn't case sensetive in the file structure, but Unix is.

Comment: mmm how do i solve that issue??

Comment: Check the file included in Routes.php and make sure the capitals and lowercase match the actual filename in the filesystem?

Comment: The folder structure for default controller is application/modules/home/controllers/Home_Controller.php and inside Home_Controller I have index function. My default controller is $route['default_controller']= 'home'. How do i make it work

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by chainging the controller file name as home_Controller from Home_Controller..